# ErrorTemplate for PasswordBox with AttachedProperty

Tags: wpf, validation, error-handling, passwordbox

I know that a passwordbox in wpf could not use the Validation.ErrorTemplate, anyhow i have to show the user, that something is wrong.

My Passwordbox has a binding like this

```
 <PasswordBox Name="Password" local:PasswordHelper.Text="{Binding PasswordProp, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Is it possible to get the same style like the default errortemplate (red border) for this passwordbox, if something is wrong?

This is my ErrorTemplate that I use for the other controls

```
<Style x:Key="baseControlStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Verdana" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Image x:Name="Bild" 
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                           Source="../Resources/Nein.ico" 
                           Margin="-5 0 0 0" 
                           MaxHeight="16" 
                           MaxWidth="16" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    </Image>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="myControl" />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to put an actual `TextBox` underneath the `PasswordBox` and bind the `Text` property to `PasswordProp` too and give the `TextBox` the ErrorTemplate:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Template="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource baseControlStyle}" Text="{Binding PasswordProp, Mode=TwoWay}" />    
    <PasswordBox Name="Password" local:PasswordHelper.Text="{Binding PasswordProp, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Since the controls of the ErrorTemplate will be put on an adorner layer, your error template will be displayed **on top of**  the PasswordBox event though the TextBox is underneath the PasswordBox.

Also note that I have set the `TextBox` controltemplate to `null`. Since it is not supposed to be visible it doesn't need to be rendered.